# C functions as parameters?

Tags: c

So I took a part of a code for my problem from an example but it's not working how I was expecting it.First module it's the place where I first try to use the function,second it's the definition of the function,in the 3rd module are the functions in the header(the corresponding code is at it's place)and the 4th module is some explanation I found of those functions.Can anyone help me undestand what's wrong?

First module problem:
Multiple markers at this line

- passing argument 1 of 'create' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
- passing argument 3 of 'create' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
- passing argument 2 of 'create' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

> repo->TList = create(cmpTrans, cpyT, delT);

Second module

```
Vector* create(CmpFun cmp, CpyFun cpy, DelFun del)
{
    Vector* v = (Vector*)malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    v->len = 0;
    v->capacity = 10;
    v->elems = (TElem)malloc(10*sizeof(TElem));
    v->cmp = cmp;
    v->del = del;
    v->cpy = cpy;
    return v;
}
```

Third module

```
transaction* cpyT(transaction* t);
void delT(transaction* t);
int cmpTrans(transaction* s1, transaction* s2);
    /*
     * Creates a copy of a transaction
     * Input: t - pointer to transaction
     * Output:  t' - a copy of transaction t
     *          t'->day = t->day; s'->type = t->type; t'->desc = t->desc; t'->amount = t->amount;
     *          * Deallocates the memory pointed to by the given instance
     * Deallocates the memory pointed to by the given instance
     * Input: t - pointer to transaction
     * Output: memory pointed to by t is deallocated
     * Input: s1, s2 - pointers to transaction
     * Output:  1 - if all the attributes of the 2 transactions coincide
     *          0 - otherwise
     */
```

Module four:

```
 typedef void* TElem;
/*
 * Pointer to a comparison function for two generic elements
 */
typedef int (*CmpFun)(TElem, TElem);

/*
 * Pointer to a function that clones (copies) a generic element
 */
typedef TElem (*CpyFun)(TElem);

/*
 * Pointer to a function that deletes (deallocates) a generic element
 */
typedef void (*DelFun)(TElem);
```

Comment: What's TElem, please add the definition to your question.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: So I don't need the return from the second module?That's all?

Comment: @MateiMarius, I don't understand that question.  Your problem isn't with the code in your second module, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function pointer typedefs all take/return `TElem` types, which means `void *`.  You're declaring functions that take/return `transaction *` types.  That makes the function pointers you make from those functions incompatible with the typedefs you created:

```
      transaction *(*)(transaction *) != TElem (*)(TElem)
int (*)(transaction *, transaction *) != int (*)(TElem, TElem)
              void (*)(transaction *) != void (*)(TElem)
```

You may be getting confused because in C, conversions between `void *` and other pointer types are implicit.  However, conversions between function pointer types, one of which takes `void *` parameters and one that doesn't, are not.

To fix it, you need to rewrite `cpyT`, `delT`, and `cmpTrans` to use the matching signatures:

```
TElem cpyT(TElem t);
void delT(TElem t);
int cmpTrans(TElem s1, TElem s2);
```

Alternatively you can force things through by typecasting when you call `create`:

```
repo->TList = create((CmpFun)cmpTrans, (CpyFun)cpyT, (DelFun)delT);
```